# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, sql

I tried something already written in the topics but it didin't worked
I got SQLSTATE[HY093]:
here is my codes;

```
   <?php
    include '

black/netting/islem.php'; 
$user = new USER();

if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
  $user->redirect('home.php');
}

?>
islem.php ;
<?php 

function tckimlik($tcno) { 
  $olmaz=array('11111111110','22222222220','33333333330','44444444440','55555555550','66666666660','7777777770','88888888880','99999999990'); 

  if($tckimlik[0]==0 or !ctype_digit($tckimlik) or strlen($tckimlik)!=11){ return false;  } 
  else{

    for($a=0;$a<9;$a=$a+2){ $ilkt=$ilkt+$tckimlik[$a]; } 
      for($a=1;$a<9;$a=$a+2){ $sont=$sont+$tckimlik[$a]; } 
        for($a=0;$a<10;$a=$a+1){ $tumt=$tumt+$tckimlik[$a]; } 
          if(($ilkt*7-$sont)%10!=$tckimlik[9] or $tumt%10!=$tckimlik[10]){ return false; } 
        else{  
          foreach($olmaz as $olurmu){ if($tckimlik==$olurmu){ return false; } } 
          return true; 
        } 
      } 
    } 





    if(isset($_POST['tcsorgula']))
    {
      $tcno = strip_tags($_POST['tcno']);
      $tel_no = strip_tags($_POST['tel_no']);
      $mail = strip_tags($_POST['mail']);
      $forum_name = strip_tags($_POST['forum_name']);
      $uye_sifre = strip_tags($_POST['uye_sifre']);
      $type = strip_tags($_POST['type']);
      $first_name = strip_tags($_POST['first_name']);
      $last_name = strip_tags($_POST['last_name']);
      $gender = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);
      $user_birth = strip_tags($_POST['user_birth']);

      if(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error[] = 'Lütfen geçerli bir e-mail adresi giriniz!';
      }
      else if(strlen($uye_sifre) < 6){
        $error[] = "Şifreniz en az 6 karakterden oluşmalıdır";  
      }
      else if($uye_sifre!=$sifre_tekrar)  {
        $error[] = "Lütfen şifrenizi tekrar doğru giriniz"; 
      }
      else if (isset($_POST['tcsorgula'])) {
       if(tckimlik($_POST['tcno'])){ 

       } else {
        echo "tc kimlik no sorunlu";
      }

    } 

  }

  else  {
    try
    { 
      $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT user_tcno, user_tel, user_email, user_fname FROM users WHERE user_tcno=:tcno OR user_tel=:tel_no OR user_email=:mail OR user_fname=:forum_name");
      $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$tcno, ':umail'=>$mail));
      $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if($row['user_fname']==$forum_name) {
        $error[] = "Üzgünüz forum kullanıcı adı alındı !";
      }
      else if($row['user_tel']==$tel_no) {
        $error[] = "Bu telefon numarası kayfı bulunmaktadır lütfen farklı bir telefon numarası giriniz...";
      }
      else if($row['user_email']==$mail) {
        $error[] = "Bu e-mail kayfı bulunmaktadır lütfen farklı bir e-mail adresi giriniz...";
      }
      else if($row['user_tcno']==$tcno) {
        $error[] = "Bu T.C kimlik numarası kaydı bulunmaktadır lütfen farklı bir T.C kimlik numarası  giriniz...";
      }
      else
      {
        if($user->register($first_name,$last_name,$tcno,$tel_no,$mail,$uye_sifre,$gender,$user_birth,$forum_name,$type)){  
          $user->redirect('kayit.php?joined');
        }
      }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }


  } 


  ?>

<?php 

require_once('dbconfig.php');

class USER
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);




    return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($first_name,$last_name,$tcno,$tel_no,$mail,$uye_sifre,$gender,$user_birth,$forum_name,$type)
    {
        try
        {



            $new_password = password_hash($uye_sifre, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_sirname,user_tcno,user_tel,user_email,user_pass,user_gender,user_birthd,user_fname,user_type) 
                VALUES(:user_name, :user_sirname, :user_tcno, :user_tel, :user_email, :new_password, :user_gender, :user_birthd, :forum_name, :user_type)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":user_name", $first_name);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_sirname", $last_name);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_tcno", $tcno);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_tel", $tel_no);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_email", $mail);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_fname", $forum_name);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_gender", $gender);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_birthd", $user_birth);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_type", $type);
            $stmt->bindparam(":new_password", $new_password);                                         

            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;   
        }

        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();

        }
    } ?>
```

then I got

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Your `SELECT` statement has 4 parameter placeholders.  But you bind only two values to it.  And neither of the bound parameters match any of the placeholders.

Comment: You didn't `bindParam(':forum_name', $forum_name)` in your `User::register` method, which i believe you renamed as `user_fname` for the bound parameter in your query.

Comment: check your first query `$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT user_tcno...` with the name placeholders that don't match and are missing some also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is showing because your parameter isn't serialized properly & your parameter number invalid. Your current parameters are :

**first check this:**

```
$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT user_tcno, user_tel, user_email, user_fname FROM users WHERE user_tcno=:tcno OR user_tel=:tel_no OR user_email=:mail OR user_fname=:forum_name");
  $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$tcno, ':umail'=>$mail));
```

**Change this to this way:**

```
$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT user_tcno, user_tel, user_email,   user_fname FROM users WHERE user_tcno=:tcno OR user_tel=:tel_no OR user_email=:mail OR user_fname=:forum_name");
  $stmt->execute(array(':tcno'=>$tcno, ':tel_no'=> $telNo, ':mail' => $mail, ':forum_name' => $forumName));
```

**and now here:**

```
 $stmt->bindparam(":user_name", $first_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_sirname", $last_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_tcno", $tcno);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_tel", $tel_no);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_email", $mail);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_fname", $forum_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_gender", $gender);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_birthd", $user_birth);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_type", $type);
        $stmt->bindparam(":new_password", $new_password);
```

**You have to change them as like this:**

```
 $stmt->bindparam(":user_name", $first_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_sirname", $last_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_tcno", $tcno);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_tel", $tel_no);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_email", $mail);
        $stmt->bindparam(":new_password", $new_password);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_fname", $forum_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_gender", $gender);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_birthd", $user_birth);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_type", $type);
```

Now hopes this error will go away.

Comment: Is it just me or did you copy and paste what OP posted

Comment: order of params do not generate the `Invalid parameter number:` error. The OP is missing parameters, in both query statements.

Comment: I have updated the answer please check and if that helps then remove that negative marks. and approve it.

Comment: @Smalldeveloper Check the `User::register` query as well, the parameters there are also not correct, and would generate the same error.

Comment: register parameter also wrong I guess could you help me also?

Comment: @H.Yılmazer the `User::register` `INSERT` query parameter tokens do not match the bound parameter keys, which is not resolved in this answer. Effectively `$stmt->bindparam(":user_fname", $forum_name);` needs to be changed to `$stmt->bindparam(":forum_name", $forum_name);` Since `user_fname` is not assigned as a parameter token within the query. Otherwise rename `:forum_name` to `:user_fname` in the `INSERT` query

Comment: @fyrye Thank you for your reply, actually i didn't noticed that sorry for that. so now i hope all the problem solved :) of H.Yilmazer . thank you for accepting answer :)

Comment: I did İt. but still I can't register. All errors disappeared but how do I register I still don't know. I know I'm beginner but would you help me to register ?

Comment: What type of problem is showing up now ? please describe to understand

Comment: the problem is nothing (at least just didn't tell me chrome) now but I can't insert information to to my database

Comment: Then might be problem with your database. please check your database properly and if you are using `PDO` then enable error mode like this ` $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` . this is so hard to understand if there is no errors found on your code.